# Django, randomization of "default" parameter of a model

Tags: django, django-models

I want to set the "default" value as a randomly generated String for the promotion_code part of my Promotion model, for that the code_generate function is used.

The issue with the code below that it seems like `default=code_generate()` generates this random string once every server start thus assigning the same value. I can see that by the admin panel, every time I try to generate a new Promotion, it gives me the exact same string.

```
#generate a string, which is not already existing in the earlier Promotion instances
def code_generate():
    while 1:
        from django.conf import settings
        import random, string
        prom_code = ''.join(random.choice(string.ascii_uppercase + string.digits) for x in range(6))
        try:
            Promotion.objects.get(promotion_code=prom_code)
        except:
            return prom_code

class Promotion(models.Model):
    purchase = models.ForeignKey('Purchase')
    promotion_code = models.CharField(max_length=20,unique=True,default=code_generate())
```

How can I make it random ?

Regards

Comment: You should be using `except Promotion.DoesNotExist:` instead.

Answer (score 24):

You need to pass a callable as `default`, not call the callable:

```
promotion_code = models.CharField(max_length=20,unique=True,default=code_generate)
```

Comment: Just for anyone who's wondering why this is the case, when you include the `()` on the callable, it's called right then and there when the model is defined. So, the **result of that call** becomes the default - so it'll be the same each time. Without the brackets, the default is the callable itself, and Django knows to call it each time to get the correct (different) value.

Comment: Interestingly, when South freezes a model, the callable is run and its return value is frozen into the `default=` argument in the ` db.create_table(...` statement in the schema migration.

Comment: Same issue as hobs's here. How should I avoid that?

Answer (score -3):

As indicated in [the other answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2257635/django-unique-field-generation/2257687#2257687), the simplest way to get a random string is as follows:

```
str(random.random())[2:]
```

Altho' it is a string of numbers. Fair enough, until you would want to replace it eventually with sha.

Comment: Answer unrelated to question.